# Discord.js v14 Interaction failed when clicking on button but button still works

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hello I'm having some issues with a discord bot. I made a command that can start a queue for players to join to create a custom game. I ran the command in my test discord and it showed the Embed along with the Join button, however when you click the button it says interaction failed but it does count the player as the number in the Embed goes up by 1. I'm not really sure what the problem is and I'd really appreciate any help offered to me.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed, MessageButton, MessageActionRow, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('queue')
    .setDescription('Starts a queue for Valorant custom games.'),
  async execute(interaction) {

const MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 10;

const queue = [];

const joinButton = new ButtonBuilder()
  .setCustomId('joinQueue')
  .setLabel('Join Queue')
  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
  .setDisabled(false);

const queueEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('Valorant Custom Game Queue')
  .setDescription(`Current Queue Size: ${queue.length}/${MAX_QUEUE_SIZE}`);

const queueMessage = await interaction.reply({
  embeds: [queueEmbed],
  components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(joinButton)],
  fetchReply: true,
});

const collector = queueMessage.createMessageComponentCollector({
  filter: (i) => i.customId === 'joinQueue' && !queue.includes(i.user.id),
  time: 60000,
});

collector.on('collect', (buttonInteraction) => {

  queue.push(buttonInteraction.user.id);


  if (queue.length >= MAX_QUEUE_SIZE) {
    joinButton.setDisabled(true);
  }


  queueEmbed.setDescription(`Current Queue Size: ${queue.length}/${MAX_QUEUE_SIZE}`);
  queueMessage.edit({
    embeds: [queueEmbed],
    components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(joinButton)],
  });
});

collector.on('end', () => {

    const queuedPlayers = queue.join('\n');
  

    const fullEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Valorant Custom Game Queue')
      .setDescription(`Queue is now full with ${queue.length} players!`)
      .addField('Queued Players:', queuedPlayers);
  

    if (queue.length === MAX_QUEUE_SIZE) {
      queueMessage.edit({
        embeds: [fullEmbed],
        components: [],
      });
  

      queue.length = 0;
    }
  });

  }
}
```

It's basically just suppose to count who's reacting with the join button and put an Embed in chat when the count reaches the MAX_QUEUE_SIZE. I plan on making it more advance as I go but as the moment this is just the basics of what I want it to do. I should also mention I am very new to coding and I'm learning rapidly but I'm stuck on this at the moment so I apologize if I wasted anyone's time with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discord wants every interaction to be replied to, otherwise it says that the interaction has failed.

In your code, you are editing the message, not replying to the button interaction. So Discord thinks you didn't complete anything when your button was called, so it says the interaction has failed.

Therefore, to fix this, you just need to reply to your `buttonInteraction` instead of `queueMessage`:

```js
collector.on('collect', (buttonInteraction) => {

  queue.push(buttonInteraction.user.id);


  if (queue.length >= MAX_QUEUE_SIZE) {
    joinButton.setDisabled(true);
  }


  queueEmbed.setDescription(`Current Queue Size: ${queue.length}/${MAX_QUEUE_SIZE}`);
  buttonInteraction.update({
    embeds: [queueEmbed],
    components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(joinButton)],
  });
});
```

Note that you need to use the `update` function of your `buttonInteraction`, since you are just updating the message the button is atteched to.

That should fix your problem. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked beautifully and I really appreciate you explaining how it works and why my previous version did not work as this makes moving forward so much easier for me.